# trouble with layout android Not Able to generate this View According to icons and line and below text

Tags: android, xml

I am designing following layout structure for one of my application. But dont know how to implement it.

[image]

Comment: Its simply Stepper procedure. You can implement by yourself or use third library for it.

Comment: @Piyush i know how to design it..but the problem is how to draw lines from half of that icon

Answer (score 0):

This Design is called Stepper. There are lot of open source library is available for this design. Check the following link. May it will help you.

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3049